# How to build torch-android

Tags: android, torch

I want to build torch-android on server(Ubuntu) in the light of the procedure showed on https://github.com/soumith/torch-android. But when I run the build.sh, the script can not find the GPU(the server has Tesla K80):

```
CMake Error at install/share/cmake/torch/FindCUDA/select_compute_arch.cmake:91 (message):
  Only
  Fermi;Kepler;Kepler+Tegra;Kepler+Tesla;Maxwell;Maxwell+Tegra;Pascal;All;Manual;Auto
  architecture names are supported.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  distro/extra/cutorch/lib/THC/CMakeLists.txt:62 (CUDA_SELECT_NVCC_ARCH_FLAGS)
```

Open build.sh, we can find

```
#!/bin/bash
# have ndk-build in your $PATH and the script figures out where your ANDROID_NDK is at.
# optionally, modify the variables below as needed.
NDKABI=21
NDKVER=toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9

ARCH=${ARCH:-"v7n"}

if [[ "$ARCH" == "v8" ]]; then
    APP_ABI=arm64-v8a
    M_ARCH=-march=arm8-a
    ABI_NAME=aarch64-linux-androideabi
    COMPUTE_NAME=Maxwell-M
elif [[ "$ARCH" == "v7n" ]]; then
    APP_ABI="armeabi-v7a with NEON"
    M_ARCH="-march=armv7-a"
    ABI_NAME=armv7-linux-androideabi
    COMPUTE_NAME=Kepler-M
elif [[ "$ARCH" == "v7" ]]; then
    APP_ABI="armeabi-v7a"
    M_ARCH="-march=armv7-a"
    ABI_NAME=armv7-linux-androideabi
    COMPUTE_NAME=Kepler
fi

    NVCC=`which nvcc`
export MAKE=make
export MAKEARGS=-j$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)
```

I think I should modify the build.sh, but I have no idea of it. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have you run these command in the ternimal?

1. `cd ~/torch-android;`
2. `git submodule update --init --recursive;`
3. `./build;`